# svn conflict between cmd line and Subversive?

Tags: svn

I'm a bit of a novice at svn and, despite repeated tries, have not been able to resolve a problem I seem to have in my environment.

I'm using svn 1.6.15 and I have Eclipse 3.5.2 with Subversive SVN Connectors 2.2.1 and SVNKit 1.3.0 Implementation on CentOS 5.5.

When I first began using svn I had checked some stuff in from the cmd line in what is now the parent directory of all of my projects. I thought I had gotten rid of all of that stuff when I started with Eclipse/Subversive but an entry for one of those original projects still remains in the .svn/entries file of the parent directory. If I do an svn list (with no arguments) from the cmd line in the parent directory the single source file for that old project is displayed. If I do an svn list and specify the URL for the repository then all of my projects are listed (but not that old source file).

If I do svn status -u from the cmd line in the parent directory all of my projects are listed with a status of ? (not under source control) although within Eclipse the projects are connected to the repository, I can see the history and do commits, etc. Another difference is that I can create new SVN projects under Eclipse but when I try to do that from the command line the new projects are created under the old, improperly removed path instead of under the path that actually still exists.

I can see the difference in the entries file in the .svn directory of the parent directory, which displays:

svn://our_SVN_url/svn/ifx/removed_directory
svn://our_SVN_url/svn/ifx

where the entries file for one of the projects that I created in Eclipse displays:

svn://our_SVN_url/svn/ifx/project_directory
svn://our_SVN_url/svn

I have tried various svn commands to cleanup, update and remove the old directory but the commit always fails for one reason or another. The directory structure for the old, improperly removed project remains in the parent directory. I tired to re-commit the source file for the old project to the repository (in hopes that I could then remove the project) but that failed as svn complains that the file is not found.

Sorry for the long-winded description but I'm not sure I understand what's going on well enough to provide a more concise one.

Thanks in advance to anyone who has a suggestion on how I can stop chasing my tail on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the command-line version of svn is different from the Eclipse plugin version.  If the two are using different specifications for svn, then projects managed under one can not be managed from the other.

Do you have all of your code checked in currently?  If so, the easiest fix would be to delete all of your local code and then do a fresh checkout.  If you still need certain files checked in, but those checkins currently fail, move your local code to another location and then do a fresh checkout.  Replace any individual files that need to be updated and then check in.  (Note that you do not want to move entire folders, as the .svn folders should not be copied.)